# Bootstrap navbar-right appears on the bottom when resizing the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want the navbar-right to stay on the right of the navbar when I resized the screen on mobile phone size.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="admin_nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" id="side_menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Welcome, Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: What is bootstrap version used?

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: check the answer provided

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space:nowrap` to the `ul`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="admin_nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" id="side_menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="white-space: nowrap">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Welcome, Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

https://www.bootply.com/eiNgzrimN2#

Answer (score 0):

**use this code**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify the difference of collapse nav bar items and fixed nav bar items in mobile view, I added both ways in order to understand how it applies. And I am using bootstrap version 3.3.7

```css
.navmenu-mobile {
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .logo-center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="logo-center navbar-brand">
        <a href="/">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-inline visible-xs navmenu-mobile" style="">
        <li><a href="#">Right Nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Right Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle banner-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Week<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sunday</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#">docs</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#">help</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle banner-username-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#" class="banner-dropdown-link">Your Info</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="banner-dropdown-link">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```